# how to assign a block of html code to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html

what is the syntax to store a block of html code to a javascript variable?

```
<div class='saved' >
<div >test.test</div> <div class='remove'>[Remove]</div></div>
```

I want to assign the above code to a variable 'test'

```
var test = "<div class='saved' >
<div >test.test</div> <div class='remove'>[Remove]</div></div>";
```

but it does not work, which are the correct syntax for assigning the code?

TIA

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? You can't have a line break in there but other than that the syntax is fine.

Comment: Thanks Cfreak, the line break(s) was the problem

Comment: So if you minify your html, it can be put in one string?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
 var test = "<div class='saved' >"+
 "<div >test.test</div> <div class='remove'>[Remove]</div></div>";
```

You can add "\n" if you require line-break.

Comment: Thanks Dragan, it was the 2 line breaks that was in the html text code.

Comment: Why do you use single quotes in HTML?

Comment: @ram4nd I c/p code from post, but you're right, `'<div class="saved">'...` would be better.

Comment: "You can add "\n" if you require line-break." Can you? According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5125874/719457 you can't.

Comment: what about single quote within double quote? i.e `<a onclick="return someFunc('x');">Click Me</a>`

Answer (score 55):

Greetings!  I know this is an older post, but I found it through Google when searching for "javascript add large block of html as variable".  I thought I'd post an alternate solution.

First, I'd recommend using single-quotes around the variable itself ... makes it easier to preserve double-quotes in the actual HTML code.

You can use a backslash to separate lines if you want to maintain a sense of formatting to the code:

```
var code = '<div class="my-class"> \
        <h1>The Header</h1> \
        <p>The paragraph of text</p> \
        <div class="my-quote"> \
            <p>The quote I\'d like to put in a div</p> \
        </div> \
    </div>';
```

Note: You'll obviously need to escape any single-quotes inside the code (e.g. inside the last 'p' tag)

Anyway, I hope that helps someone else that may be looking for the same answer I was ... Cheers!

Comment: Be careful when using this method of inserting extra whitespace. Especially if this javascript is heavily nested.

Comment: @BrianAyers how do we insert conditional statements here?

Answer (score 30):

we can use backticks (``) without any error.. eg: `<div>"test"<div>`

we can store large template(HTML) inside the backticks which was introduced in ES6 javascript standard

No need to escape any special characters

if no backticks.. we need to escape characters by appending backslash() 
eg:" \"test\""

Comment: This is an excellent 2017 answer. More information can be found on MDN [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: This is the best thing I have learned all week. I just... It's... so beautiful!

Comment: This would have been nice solution fo me, but Template literals is not supported in IE11, https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals.

Comment: Excellent indeed!! This is very useful specially when the HTML code is from another source. Thanks

Comment: Wow, this saved my day! Thank you so much, I had no idea we could use back ticks!

Answer (score 7):

I recommend to use `mustache` templating frame work. https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/.

```
<body>
       ....................
       <!--Put your html variable in a script and set the type to "x-tmpl-mustache"-->
       <script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
           <div class='saved' >
           <div >test.test</div> <div class='remove'>[Remove]</div></div>
    </script>
</body>

  //You can use it without jquery.
  var template = $('#template').html();
  var rendered = Mustache.render(template);
  $('#target').html(rendered);
```

**Why I recommend this?**

Soon or latter you will try to replace some part of the HTML variable and make it dynamic. Dealing with this as an HTML `String` will be a headache. Here is where Mustache magic can help you.

```
<script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
 <div class='remove'>  {{ name }}! </div> ....
</script>
```

and

```
 var template = $('#template').html();
 // You can pass dynamic template values
  var rendered = Mustache.render(template, {name: "Luke"});
  $('#target').html(rendered);
```

There are lot more features.

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, here is a benchmark of different technique rendering performances,

http://jsperf.com/zp-string-concatenation/6

m,

Answer (score 2):

Modern Javascript implementations with the `template` syntax using backticks are also an easy way to assign an HTML block of code to a variable:

```
    const firstName = 'Sam';
    const fullName = 'Sam Smith';
    const htmlString = `<h1>Hello ${fullName}!</h1><p>This is some content \
        that will display. You can even inject your first name, ${firstName}, \
        in the code.</p><p><a href="http://www.google.com">Search</a> for \
        stuff on the Google website.</p>`;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make a javascript object with key being name of the html snippet, and value being an array of html strings, that are joined together.

```
var html = {
  top_crimes_template:
    [
      '<div class="top_crimes"><h3>Top Crimes</h3></div>',
      '<table class="crimes-table table table-responsive table-bordered">',
        '<tr>',
          '<th>',
            '<span class="list-heading">Crime:</span>',
          '</th>',
          '<th>',
            '<span id="last_crime_span"># Arrests</span>',
          '</th>',
        '</tr>',
      '</table>'
    ].join(""),
  top_teams_template:
    [
      '<div class="top_teams"><h3>Top Teams</h3></div>',
      '<table class="teams-table table table-responsive table-bordered">',
        '<tr>',
          '<th>',
            '<span class="list-heading">Team:</span>',
          '</th>',
          '<th>',
            '<span id="last_team_span"># Arrests</span>',
          '</th>',
        '</tr>',
      '</table>'
    ].join(""),
  top_players_template:
    [
      '<div class="top_players"><h3>Top Players</h3></div>',
      '<table class="players-table table table-responsive table-bordered">',
        '<tr>',
          '<th>',
            '<span class="list-heading">Players:</span>',
          '</th>',
          '<th>',
            '<span id="last_player_span"># Arrests</span>',
          '</th>',
        '</tr>',
      '</table>'
    ].join("")
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use symbol backtick '`' in your front and end of html string, this is so called template literals, now you able to write pure html in multiple lines and assign to variable.

Example >>

```
var htmlString =

`

<span>Your</span>
<p>HTML</p>

`
```