# How do I render a Django template as a string when using the include tag?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

Long story short, I am trying to include a Django template as a string, and I would like to do something like this in a script tag:

```
<script>
    var template = '{% include "mytemplate.html" %}';
</script>
```

Right now I keep getting an invalid or unexpected token error, with the following output:

```
var template = '<h1>Hello World</h1>
'
```

Which makes me wonder if there's some sort of newline character taking effect at the end? And it seems to be taking effect before I can do anything about it since things like .trim() don't seem to work.

Comment: You want to store your template html in javascript variable?

Comment: Why you put your html template as javascript variable, what actually you need to do? I think it bad idea, but if you realy need to store your html template as javascript variable you can following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3410286/6396981, but I'm don't know how to add character `+`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this below way.

```
  <script> var template = '{% spaceless %}{% include "mytemplate.html" %}{% endspaceless %}'; </script>
```

Comment: This answer does not work. It produces javascript syntax error. The correct way is to use the `render_to_string` method.

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because inside your HTML template there are newline characters which are not accepted by javascript variables.

There are 2 ways to solve this but first you must store the rendered template in a variable (inside your `views.py` file) using [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string), like this:

```
# views.py

def my_view(request):
    tmpl = render_to_string('the_included_template.html'))
    return render(request, 'a_template.html', {'tmpl': tmpl})
```

1. Now, you can use the ES2015 specification's [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax, like this:

   ```
   <script>
       var template = `{{ tmpl }}`;  \\ backticks here
   </script>
   ```
2. Or, if you do not want to use the *template literals* inside your HTML, then you have to remove any newline characters from `tmpl`. Like this (kudos to `NeErAj KuMaR`'s answer below, I forgot about the [`{% spaceless %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless) template tag!):

   ```
   <script>
       var template = '{% spaceless %}{{ tmpl }}{% endspaceless %}';  \\ no backticks here
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Thanks. It appears that the template literal method works as well, but I'm pretty sure browser support is still a problem.

Comment: Not exactly a problem... http://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals. Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

If you are rendering your html using django-template. Then you can use variable inside include tag to render child template like this:

```
content = "template1.html"    #child template located in templates folder of your app
```

then in parent.html, you can define:

```
 {% include ""|add:content with title=title %}
```