# Storing part of html page in a variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some HTML like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 no-padding--xs" style="text-align:right; padding-left:30rem">
<div class="no-padding--xs box--lang">
<a href="Intranet_sk.html"><img style="width:30px" src="Intranet_flags/flag-SVK-round.png"></a>
<a href="Intranet_en.html"><img style="width:30px"src="Intranet_flags/flag-UK-round.png"></a>
</div> 
</div>
</div>
```

and I want to keep it in the upper part of page layout but use it in the lower part of the (rendered) page, a bit like if you store the code in a variable and use the variable in specific part of the page.

The whole Intranet will be made of many modules but this one will be unique for every "subpage" so I want to keep the editable code in the upper part of the page layout  and call/publish it using a lower static module.

Why? the "`Intranet_`" in href part will be unique for every subpage.

Alternatively, could I attach "`_sk`" or "`_en`" to the subpage metaname and create the link like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to assign a block of html code to a javascript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410198/how-to-assign-a-block-of-html-code-to-a-javascript-variable)

Comment: Are you using a particular server software package? 'subpage metaname' and 'layout page' seem to have specific meanings to you that they don't have to other people, so it's difficult to know exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store html code in a normal string and add it to any html element by doing `element.innerHTML += stringThatContainsHTML`

You can also retrieve HTML in the same way `var htmlString = element.innerHTML`

Comment: Your answer is redundant, because it explains exactly the same, if not less, than the "possible duplicate of" answer.

Comment: thanx, it really was that simple :) I made <script> var: storage = .....</script> in head and then in body I have <div id="lang"><script>document.getElementById("lang").innerHTML = storage;</script></div>

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an element (`document.createElement`)
2. Append clones of the necessary elements to that (`[createdElement].appendChild([someElement].cloneNode([true]))`)
3. Reuse whatever you need from within the element created (`[createdElement].querySelector[All](...)`)

Essential here: the created element only exists in memory (is not inserted/appended in the DOM).